# CrossRider API, get opened tabs title

Tags: javascript, jquery, crossrider

I am using the CrossRider api to get the opened tabs, using there API I can get the title of the links in my bookmarks, however with there api I cannot use how to get the title of the urls in my opened tabs, I can just get the URL.

Does anyone know if this is achievable, if not then if there is some other way. Current I have to call a php script to make calls to the URLs and extract the title, this is getting too slow with a lot of tabs open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great if you included a code snippet to show how your code works. However, in the absence of a snippet, I'm guessing that you are working in the background scope using an API method such as [appAPI.tabs.getAllTabs](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs). As you correctly surmised, the method does no not provide the title of the URL.

There are several way to work around this, on of which you mentioned, however, I prefer getting the information from the tab itself through messaging. For example, assuming you still need the information in the background scope:

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.message.listener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.action==='tab-info') {
      doSomething(msg.data);
    }
  });
  appAPI.message.toAllTabs({action:'get-tab-info'});
});
```

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.message.listener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.action==='get-tab-info') {
      appAPI.message.toBackground({
        action:'tab-info',
        data: {
          tabId: appAPI.getTabId(),
          url: appAPI.dom.location.href,
          title: document.title
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: tried to do this and also get the first tab returned, and also the title is not yet, the url and tab id are!

Comment: ok fixed that error, but the problem is that the extension.js script does not work with sites with https, can you suggest what to do?

Comment: _extension.js_ does run on https sites. Is there a particular site that you are having issues with? Sometimes pages can take a long time to complete loading and hence delay the ready event.

Comment: I have tested on facebook.com, google.com, and about 5 other sites! it works for non https sites, can you please advice if you have any recommendations

Comment: I've definitely tested HTTPS on those site with Chrome and it works. How are you determining that the extension.js file isn't running? You can test this easily by adding console.log messages before an after appAPI.ready and check if they appear in the console. I'm happy to take a look as well if you provide the extension id.

Comment: thank you very much! my app id is: 66480 it is still in staging mode!

Comment: I tested the extension using Chrome on the aforementioned HTTPS pages and I get the alert as expected: [google.com](http://screencast.com/t/v1gkKlNM), [facebook.com](http://screencast.com/t/dQPiifyybbm). Do you have any other extensions or software that may be blocking the extension?